# Entity Framework One-To-Many with only one navigation property: WithRequiredDependant?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Using the newest Entity Framework I have a class with a one-to-many wit only one navigation property on the many side.

As stated in [MSDN: Entity Framework Fluent API - Relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> A one-directional (also called unidirectional) relationship is when a
>   navigation property is defined on only one of the relationship ends
>   and not on both.

Simplified: a `School` has many `Students`; there is a one-to-many relation between School and Student, but the School doesn't have a property containing the collection of Students

```
class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // a Student attends one School; foreign key SchoolId
    public int SchoolId {get; set;}
    public School School {get; set;}
}

class School
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // missing: public virtual ICollection<Studen> Students {get; set;}
}
```

In a two-directional relationship, you could write the following fluent API in `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
        .HasRequired(student => student.School)
        .WithMany(school => school.Students)
        .HasForeignKey(student => student.SchoolId);
}
```

Because of the lack of `School.Students`, I need to do something extra. According to the link at the beginning it seems that I'd have to do something with `WithRequiredDependant`.

```
// Summary:
//     Configures the relationship to be required without a navigation property
//     on the other side of the relationship. The entity type being configured will
//     be the dependent and contain a foreign key to the principal. The entity type
//     that the relationship targets will be the principal in the relationship.
//
public ForeignKeyNavigationPropertyConfiguration WithRequiredDependent();

modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasRequired(student => student.School)
    .WithRequiredDependent();
```

Alas, this doesn't work. SchoolId is not modeled as the foreign key.

What fluent API do I need?

Comment: Did you try `WithRequiredPrincipal` instead of `WithRequiredDependent`?

Comment: "Using the newest ..."  - better be clear about the exact versions and if it's Core or not. This question should still mean something in a few months.

Comment: Of course I tried both WithRequired..., I didn't mention that, because question was already so long. With "the newest"  I meant that I am prepared to update to whatever version I need, to prevent answers like: "if you would upgrade to version ... you could use ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I have the right version/edition in mind:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasRequired(student => student.School)
  //.WithMany(school => school.Students)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(student => student.SchoolId);
```

Comment: That's it: WithMany() without parameters! It has nothing to do with RequiredPrincipal and RequiredDependant. I found out that is used in a required:required relation (is that one-to-one?)